# Is there a correct way to run?

Tags: running, foot

I started to run two days ago, but i am not sure if i am doing this correctly.

I am interested in know if there is some tips and tricks about run, dos & don'ts.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, don't see this topic in the suggestion.

Comment: I agree, the other one talks about what is the source of pain or injury due to running. On the other hand this is a very general question :)